# What is the best way to skip a full page in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm using an image as a full-screen background. When I put a new div underneath the content of the div gets mish-mashed with the image instead of allowing scrolling.

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  ;
}

body {
  background-color: #FBEEC1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#header {
  background-image: url(tempbackground.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
}

#title-text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  /* divide each margin in 1/2 */
  margin-top: -125px;
}

​ .body-text {
  display: none;
  /*This will be enables after scrolling with a scroll animation */
  color: #BC986A;
  width: 100%;
}

.text-width {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.font-title {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

.font-body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img id="title-text" src="Logo-text.png">
</div>
<div class="body-text" id="font-title">&nbsp;
  <h2 class="text-width">Our Forests Are Under Attack!</h2>
  <p class="text-width" id="font-body">Sample text that should display below image.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what i understood, you want that the page you first up see after opening your file in browser **to be blank** and when you **scroll down** you see your content.
for this make a empty  container 
  `<div class="empty-page"></div>`  and set its height in css file to `100 vh`( viewport height ).

```css
.empty-page { 
      height: 100vh;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="empty-page"></div>
    <!-- your rest of the code -->
    <h1>THIS IS A HEADING</h1>   
</body>
```